# how to connect Microsoft Azure to on-premises sql database

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to connect a Microsoft Azure Web Site to a SQL Server Database hosted on-premises and, if so, what the steps that I need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Let any request in coming from you Azure Web Site IP and targeting TCP port 1433 through your firewall . Then change your connectionString on your Azure Web Site to point to the public gateway used on premsie.

Comment: FYI - Azure Web Sites do not have a dedicated outbound IP address. If you set up SSL, you only get a dedicated inbound IP address. So you won't be able to filter just Azure Web Sites traffic for a single web site.

Answer (score 0):

As @qux mentioned, you need to allow for inbound traffic on port 1433. With Azure Web Sites, you won't have a dedicated outbound IP address, so you'll need to rely on a secure SQL Server configuration.

If you shift to Cloud Services (web role / worker role), then you *will* have an IP address to filter against. Same thing with Virtual Machines.

You can also set up a VPN (and there are many VPN appliances certified with Azure).